# Facebook Custom Audience Pixel Urls/Domains List

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having a hard time in fb docs to find how I can get a list of all the urls/hosts that I placed my custom audience pixels or any other tracking pixels. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/facebook-pixel/website-custom-audiences/v2.4

I'm able to get the info through the stats endpoint but that seems to be overkill for me to populate a dropdown list in my web application.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/custom-audience-website-pixel-stats/v2.4

Any suggestion would greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're placing the pixel manually you could keep track of the URLs yourself, otherwise I think only the /stats endpoint will return stats about where the pixel was fired from and which events were fired

Comment: That's what I ultimately decided to do at this point. Fetch 3 days worth of stats, parsed and return the unique urls, and then have it cached.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to the Business Manager https://business.facebook.com/ and click
  the hamburger menu at the top left.
- Click Pixels and then the pixel you want to check
- Underneath the graph are some options. Click Domains to see the top level URLs or URLs for a more detailed list

I can't find any way of doing this in code I'm afraid.